# Relationship Problem in SQL (Column can't be cascaded)

Tags: sql-server-2005, relationships

I have 3 tables (Patient,Doctor,Appointments) 
patient has a primary key(Patient_ID)and a foreign key (Doctor_ID)
Doctor has a primary key(Doctor_ID)
Appointments has a primary key(Appo_ID)and two foreign keys(Patient_ID,Doctor_ID)
here is the problem,In the relationship diagram the two relations(Patient.Patient_ID,App.Patient_ID & Doctor.Doctor_ID,Appo.Doctor_ID) can't be cascade at once,
if one is cascade, the other show this error message

```
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Appointments_Doctor'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Appointments_Doctor' on table 'Appointments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

and this is my procedure for updating

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateDoc
    @Doctor_ID INT,@Name NVARCHAR(50),@Salary MONEY,@Hire_Date DATETIME,@Dept_ID INT,@Old_ID int
AS

    Update Doctor
    Set 
        @Old_ID=Doctor_ID,
    Doctor_ID=@Doctor_ID,
    [Name] =@Name,
    Salary=@Salary,
    Hire_Date=@Hire_Date,
    Dept_ID=@Dept_ID
    Where Doctor_ID=@Old_ID
Return
```

If there any question for more specific, ask me

Comment: I think the problem may be, that for some reason, you've set the foreign key from patients to doctors to cascade delete? Do you really run a system where, if a doctor is removed, all patients associated with that doctor are removed? And since Patients are linked to Doctors directly, why are they also present in Appointments. One of these two doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @dam post this as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @Erik - it doesn't really answer the question, in my view. I'd rather understand why Doctors is FKed from both Patients and Appointments, then post a reasonable solution :-)

Comment: but when updating the id of the Doctor it must be updated on the patient table am i right? and the appointment may be made by another Doctor>>>>>:D It's my Database

Comment: I mean a patient has a doctor that is responsible for him and other appointments may be made by another doctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cyclic dependency, why would you want it to cascade? And why are you updating the `Doctor_ID` strictly speaking you shouldn't ever be updating (setting) the primary key.

That you are filtering `Where Doctor_ID=@Doctor_ID` on the same value you are updating `Set Doctor_ID=@Doctor_ID` tells me you haven't tought this through.

Comment: that's ok why i found a solution to this but thet is not my question

Comment: my question is the previous (the relationship problem on not cascading)

Comment: i updated the procedure but the relationship problem that is the main problem, help me plz

Comment: Remove the cascading behaviour. It's not needed for referential integrity.

Comment: I need it in updating when update in the doctor table(Doctor_ID) or patient table(Patient_ID) it makes the sam on the appointments

Comment: But that's not how you operate a RDMS. Firstly, you won't be changing the `Doctor_ID`. Secondly, any information about the `Doctor_ID` is added by joining that table. This way the cascading update is not needed. Changes to the doctor are always reflected through-out the system. And the same thing goes for patients and appointments. I believe you've misunderstood the usage of cascades.

Comment: :D :D :D You are right , but I need to make changes to Doctor_ID that what i built my project in , sorry I will make changes to this database now

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you update Doctor_ID since you have it in the WHERE clause:

```
   Update Doctor
    Set 
    Doctor_ID=@Doctor_ID,
    ....
    Where Doctor_ID=@Doctor_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic problem.
If you define a connection between patient and doctor, that you cannot define an appointment related to both. Choose just one of them and you'll get the other.

Try to model the database using the business logic of the real world example.
So you have doctors and patients, ok? If the doctors are dedicated to a patient and one doctor will attend always the same patient than you create a foreign key relating them. Then for appointments, the appointment is related with a patient and because the patient is automatically related with a doctor, the appointment only needs the patient foreign key.

Comment: ok ,but the apoointment can made by another Doctor in the hospital do u get it?

Comment: do you also have a fk relating the doctors to patients?